# How to create sub urls from document ids in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, url-routing, google-cloud-firestore

I have a website: `https://irlmap.com`

When a user loads this site, I create a new document in Firebase which stores user data. Let's pretend the id of this document is `1234`.

Once this document is created, I want it to be possible to navigate to `https://irlmap.com/1234` and for that url to load some view.

I have never done anything like this before and I don't know what doing this is "called," and so I'm having trouble getting started. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you're trying to do is create a dynamic web site. There are probably as many approaches to this as there are developers out there, so it's hard to recommend anything specific. Since you tagged with Reactjs, you might want to look into [how a ReactJS app can read parameters from the URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+a+ReactJS+app+can+read+parameters+from+the+URL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase npm to make things easier

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Then you need to initialize the according to your firebase configuration

// Initialize Firebase

```
  const config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX"
  };
```

In the constructor

```
firebase.initializeApp(config)
super(firebase.database().ref())
```

Now you are connected to the firebase, you can search for any value you are looking for

```
firebase.database().ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var users = snapshot.val().users;
   //loop through users or any thing else 
        });
```

Hope it will work for you